# How to calculate C for an AM demodulator?

Tags: circuit-design, filter, amplitude-modulation, demodulation

I have read this equation from Savant's book that is used to calculate the capacitor for a demodulator:

[image]

I've tried to calculate my circuit with this equation, but it didn't work. Then I tried to recalculate this example from the book, but I don't know what is 'w' here in the example:

> A 15MHz radio frequency carrier is modulated with a 5kHz signal with a modulation index (m) of 0.5. If the load resistance is 5 kOhms, what capacitor value must be added in parallel to the load to filter the radio frequency signal?
>
> response: 0.013 uF

Can you please teach me how to obtain w so I can calculate C? I tried with 15MHz, and 5kHz, but I don't get the same answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\$\omega\$ is the [angular frequency.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_frequency)

\$ \omega = 2\pi f \$

This makes your equation:
\$ C = \frac {1}{2\pi f R_Lm}\$

For your example:

\$ C = \frac {1}{2\pi (5000) (5000) (0.5)} = 0.01273239µF \approx 0.013µF\$

\$f\$ is the frequency of the modulation signal (5kHz,) not the carrier (15MHz.)

Comment: I lot of thanks, you're so kind, thank you for your answer